# Why does my section title have a different font than the text?

Tags: fonts, text

This is my code. I don't know why, but my section title and the text have different fonts. What can I do? I would be really grateful if anyone can help

```
\documentclass[parskip=half, 12pt]{scrreprt} 
%******************************************Seitenränder**********************************************
\usepackage[left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{Name}
\cfoot{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=0pt,
    afterskip=1\baselineskip plus .1\baselineskip minus .1\baselineskip
  ]{chapter}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    beforeskip=-12pt,
    afterskip=.125pt
  ]{section,subsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=-10pt,
    afterskip=.125pt
  ]{subsubsection}
%******************************************Textformat*****************************************
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %schrift

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5} 

%*********************************************other************************************************
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\normalfont
%*********************************************Title************************************************
\title{Paper}
\author{My Name}
\date{October 2022}
%*********************************************Dokument************************************************

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{title}
Text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section title uses the sans serif family. It is the default  of the class.

If you want to use the same font for  sections and subsections  as the text, use

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
beforeskip=-12pt,
afterskip=.125pt,
font=\normalfont\Large\bfseries
]{section,subsection}
```

To set all section levels at once to no longer use sans
serif fonts use

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the first line into

```
\documentclass[
  parskip=half,
  12pt,
  egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
]{scrreprt}
```

Best option name ever.

[image]